# MMM-Assistant Permission Denied

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I am very new to raspberry pi in general so if all responses could not assume any prior knowledge that would be fantastic!

My problem is, I am following the steps to install the Google Assistant module on my Magic Mirror and I'm running into a problem that hopefully someone can help with.

I have followed step by step [from here](https://github.com/eouia/MMM-Assistant/wiki) 
and the problem i'm running into is after downloading the .js filed for the OAuth they say rename the file as secret.js and place in my MMM-Assistant directory, which I just moved the file from my Downloads folder to MagicMirror/modules/MMM-Assistant folder.

Then it says "Then execute this on your MagicMirror terminal.(not via SSH)"

So, I type in `/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-Assistant/secret.json` and it says `permission denied`.  So I tried to just skip that and go to the next where it says `cd <Your MagicMirror Direcotry>/modules/MMM-Assistant/scripts/
node google-auth.js` it then says `too many arguments`. And no browser opens to give me credentials.

If someone could please help me out that would be fantastic.  I've tried doing sudo bash and then the commands but it still says permission denied and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an explanation of the errors you were getting: permission denied errors are typically caused by one of two reasons: either you don't have permission to run that file(in which case using `sudo` should fix it) or the file simply *cannot* be executed. `json` files are not executable, that is, they are simply data files. The second error you got, too many arguments, was caused by running the `cd` command with 3 arguments: `/modules/MMM-Assistant/scripts/`, `node`, and `google-auth.js`. This throws an error because `cd` requires only one argument: the directory to change into.

So your problem is simply not understanding the instructions correctly:

After renaming `client-secret-blahblahXXX.json` to `secret.json` and putting it in the `MMM-Assistant` directory,  you need to execute the following commands(*seperately*):

```
cd <Your MagicMirror Direcotry>/modules/MMM-Assistant/scripts/
```

*then*

```
node google-auth.js
```

Don't do them together.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense..I appreciate the explanation and you dumbing it down for me!  Ill give it a shot here soon.

Comment: I just tried it, went to the scripts directory within MMM-Assistant and now it's saying it can't find module MagicMirror/modules/MMM-Assistant/assets/google-client-secret.json'...any thoughts on this?  I tried moving it to this folder and trying again but nothing, Sorry I'm so needy

Comment: @Jacob , try moving `secret.json` into `MMM-Assistant/assets` and renaming it to `google-client-secret.json`

Comment: I tried renaming it and leaving it in the MMM-Assistant directory and it didn't work but that just did, thank you so much!